# Workaround for handling expectable java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory, processbuilder

I am working on a Java Web Application based on Java 6/Tomcat 6.0. It's a web based document management system. The customers may upload any kind of file to that web application. After uploading a file a new Thread is spawned, in which the uploaded file is analyzed. The analysis is done using a third party library.

This third-party-libraries works fine in about 90% of the analyze-jobs, but sometimes (depending on the uploaded file) the logic starts to use all remaining memory, leading to an OutOfMemoryError.

As the whole application is running in a single JVM, the OoM-Error is not only affecting the analyze-jobs, but has also impact on other features. In the worst case scenario, the application crashes completely or remains in an inconsistent state.

I am now looking for a rather quick (but safe) way to handle those OoM-Errors. Replacing the library currently is no option (that's why I have neither mentioned the name of the library, nor what kind of analysis is done). Does anybody have an idea of what could be done to work around this error?

I've been thinking about launching a new process (java.lang.ProcessBuilder) to have a new JVM. If the third-party-lib causes an OoM-Error there, it would not have effects on the web application. On the other hand, this would cause additional effort to synchronize the new Process with the Analysis-Part of the web application. Does anybody have any experience with such a system (especially with regards to the stability of the system)?

Some more information:
1) The analysis part can be summarized as a kind of text extraction. The module receives a file reference as input and writes the analysis result into a text file. The resulting text-file is further processed within the web applications business logic. Currently the workflow is synchronous. The business logics waits for the third-party-lib to complete its job. There is no queuing or other asynchronous approach.

2) I am quite sure that the third-party-library causes the OoM-Error. I've tested the analysis part in isolation with different files of different sizes. The file that causes the OoM-Error is quite small (about 4MB). I have done further tests with that particular file. While having a JVM with 256MB of heap, the analysis crashes due to the OoM-Error. The same test in a JVM with 512MB heap passes. However, increasing the heap size will only help for a short period of time, as a larger test file again causes the test to fail due to OoM-Error.

3) A Limit for the size of files being uploaded is in place; but of course you cannot have a limit of 4MB per file. Same is for the OS and architecture. The system has to work on both 32- and 64-bit systems (Windows and Linux)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on both the client and the server as well as the design of the web app. You need to answer a few questions:

- what is supposed to happen as a result of the analysis and when is it supposed to happen?
- Does the client wait for the result of the analysis?
- What is returned to the client?

You also need to determine the nature of the OOM.

It is possible that you might want to handle the file upload and the file analysis separately. For instance, your webapp can upload the file to somewhere in the file system and you can defer the analysis part to a web service, which would be passed a reference to the file location. The webservice may or may not be called asynchronously, depending on how and when the client that uploaded the file needs notification in the case of a problem in the analysis.

All of these factors go into your determination.

Other considerations, what JVM are you using, what is the OS and how is it configured in terms of system memory?  Is it the JVM 32 or 64 bit, what is the max file size allowed on upload, what kind of garbage collectors have you tried.

It is possible that you can solve this problem from an infrastructure perspective as opposed to changing the code. Limiting the max size of the file upload, moving from 32 to 64 bit, changing the garbage collector, upgrading libraries after determining whether or not there is a bug or memory leak in one of them, etc.

One other red flag that is glaring, you say "a thread is spawned". While this sort of thing is possible it is often frowned upon in the JEE world. Spawning threads yourself can cause problems in how the container manages resources. Make sure you are not causing the issue yourself, try a file load independently in a test environment on a file that is known to cause problems (if that can be ascertained). This will help you determine ff the problem is the third party library or a design one.

Comment: I have added some more information on the topic in my original post and I appreciate your intention to solve the "root"-problem (the OoM-Error itself). The long-term solution will of course be to update or replace the problematic library.
For now I would like to have an opportunity to somehow put the library under quarantine, while taking into account, that it will cause an OoM-Error from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a (possibly clustered) application per 3rd-party lib that handles file analysation. Those applications are called remotely (possibly asynchronously) from your main application. They are passed a URL which points to the file they should analyze and return their analysation results.

When a file upload completed the analyzation job is put into the queue. When an analyzation application is up again after it crashed it will resume consuming  messages from the queue.